# how to create a range scroller with dates on the band

Tags: javascript, php, range, scroller

I want to add a range scroller with consequent dates in a year on the band so that when chosen the difference in the dates the data within two dates will automatically show up on the graph.

I checked high charts but I am not able to get only the range scroller. I want range scroller something like shown in the image below. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[For reference](https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/advanced-stock-chart)

[image]

Comment: You need to show us your code and what you have tried so far. Currently, this question is too broad and unspecific.

Comment: i could not get the code for such kinds of scroller. i have only code for single pointer on the band\